# How could Wolverine say he remembers everything?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, x-men-days-of-future-past, marvel, x-men-origins-wolverine

At the end of *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, Professor X asks Wolverine what he remembers, and he replies "Everything".

However, the Trask incident happened in 1973 and the events of *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* happened after 1975.

It was shown in *Origins* that Stryker put adamantium inside his body and wiped his memory. Therefore, how could Wolverine say that he remembers everything that happened in 1973?

Kitty says only someone who time-travels remembers everything. Does this mean that Wolverine came from 1973 to 2023 directly, or did he live through those years again?

Comment: The version of Wolverine that said he remembered "everything" (in effect) came directly from 1973 to whatever present time was being used. He wouldn't remember the intervening years of the NEW timeline, but would still remember the original timeline, going back into time, making changes, then waking up in the altered timeline.

Comment: Exactly. This is why he seems extra shocked to see certain people running around the mansion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He remembers everything that happened from the day that he was sent back to in 1973 until he fell into the water and his mind traveled back into the future.
He does not remember anything after Day of Future Past 1973 events because his mind traveled back into the future. So you can't remember things that you did not experience.

For example: supposing you currently live in 2014. If you were to time travel to 2044, you wouldn't remember what happens in 2015-2043.Also, Wolverine never said that he remembers everything:

> Professor X: Logan, don't you have a class to teach?
>
> Logan: A class?
>
> Professor X: In history!
>
> Logan: Oh, well... I need help with some stuff. Everything from 1973.
>
> [the Professor reads his mind, and understands]
>
> Professor X: Welcome back.
>
> Logan: It's good to see you, Charles. It's good to see all of you.
>
> Professor X: I think we have a lot of catching up to do...

Comment: Wolverine doe say he remembers everything but that is in the House of M short run (HoM #3) and graphic novel compilation.

Comment: Effectively, Wolverine would be the only character who knows the events of X1, X2, X3, X-men Origins: Wolverine (and leading up to it), Wolverine (2013), and the part of TFP which is set in 2023.